# Not able to get the pdf from internet

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I am trying to download the pdf content from the internet and download it to a local file.
I am using iText for reading the pdf and using Java stream to write it.

After writing the file, new file can not be opened in the PDF reader.

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(strURL);
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(fileName));
fos.write(reader.getPageContent(1));
fos.flush();
fos.close();
```

I am trying to get the PDf from [this link](http://epaper.udayavani.com/PDF/MANIPAL/2013-06-18/man18061301medn.pdf)

I am debugged few things. Here are the findings.

> reader.getEofPos()

gives 291633, Which is same as file length.But

```
reader.getPageContent(1).length;
```

gives  only 42360 bytes. Clearly byte read are less than the actual size.

Only one page of pdf is present

```
reader.getNumberOfPages() =1
```

Do i need to specify few more things to reader to read the entire pdf file?

Comment: Handling the stream from remote http server  is not a task PdfReader meant to do.  For example can it handle link redirect?   You can use http-client libraries to download the file and then use itext for your editing.

Comment: `reader.getPageContent(1).length` returns the length of the content stream of the page. Many resources used for that page, e.g. images and fonts, are not part of that stream. Thus, that length is of no concern here. And who ever told you that the content stream of a page can be parsed as a PDF in its own right? If you can fire that person, do.

Answer (score 0):

If all you're trying to do is download a PDF from the internet and save it locally, this can be accomplished using a simple HTTP web request. An internet download is normally just an HTTP GET request, which you can accomplish by doing something like this:

```
URLConnection connection = new URL(url).openConnection();
connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", charset);
InputStream response = connection.getInputStream();
```

Once you get the **response**, you can save the bytes to a path of your choosing.